# reading XML file and extract only node names and structure

Tags: xml, xmllint, xmlstarlet

I need to audit XML file structures and need to generate a report that shows only the DOM tree structure and omit the values. Essentially, I just the node names only and no values. I tried using xmllint and xmlstarlet but can't figure out how to do this.

Does anyone know of any tools or examples of above tools that do this?

`cat $filename.xml | xmlstarlet format -t` gives me what I need, but I want to omit all values.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example input file and the output you would want from that example so we can test our answers. I realize you want a general solution, but we'll still need a file to play with.

Comment: "_I need to audit XML file structures_" if you have an XSD that describes the XML you want to validate, then there are tools such as `xmlstarlet` that will do this for you already.

Comment: Do you want to output the elements, but without textual contents? Or just the tag names used? What about attributes? What about comments or XML processing instructions? Would a straight list of each element's XPath suffice? What ave you searched/researched/tried?

Answer (score 9):

The `xmllint` interactive shell command `du` appears to provide what you want:

```
   du PATH
       Show the structure of the subtree under the given path or the current node.
```

If you want something non-interactive, then perhaps

```
printf '%s\n' du exit | xmllint --shell file.xml
```

or

```
xmllint --shell file.xml <<EOF
du
exit
EOF
```

ex.

```
$ printf '%s\n' du exit | xmllint --shell rss.xml
/ > /
rss
  channel
    title
    link
    description
    copyright
    language
    lastBuildDate
    image
      url
      title
      link
    item
      title
      link
      description
      pubDate
    item
      title
      link
      description
      pubDate
    item
      title
      link
      description
      pubDate
/ >
```

Comment: this was perfect. thanks. option 2 worked well.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're already using `xmlstarlet` you may as well continue using it.

The `xmlstarlet` tool has an `el` (`elements`) sub-command which is used to "Display element structure of XML document".

By default, it outputs data like this:

```
$ xmlstarlet el /usr/X11R6/share/xcb/ge.xml
xcb
xcb/request
xcb/request/field
xcb/request/field
xcb/request/reply
xcb/request/reply/pad
xcb/request/reply/field
xcb/request/reply/field
xcb/request/reply/pad
```

You may also get attributes:

```
$ xmlstarlet el -a /usr/X11R6/share/xcb/ge.xml
xcb
xcb/@header
xcb/@extension-xname
xcb/@extension-name
xcb/@major-version
xcb/@minor-version
xcb/request
xcb/request/@name
xcb/request/@opcode
xcb/request/field
xcb/request/field/@type
xcb/request/field/@name
xcb/request/field
xcb/request/field/@type
xcb/request/field/@name
xcb/request/reply
xcb/request/reply/pad
xcb/request/reply/pad/@bytes
xcb/request/reply/field
xcb/request/reply/field/@type
xcb/request/reply/field/@name
xcb/request/reply/field
xcb/request/reply/field/@type
xcb/request/reply/field/@name
xcb/request/reply/pad
xcb/request/reply/pad/@bytes
```

See also `xmlstarlet el --help`.

Using the `val` (`validate`) sub-command ("Validate XML document(s) (well-formed/DTD/XSD/RelaxNG)"), `xmlstarlet` may validate your XML document for you.  It will, by default, just check whether the document is well formed, but it may also validate your document against a provided XSD schema, the document's DTD, or an Relax-NG schema.

See also `xmlstarlet val --help`.